# Lorentz space embedding

Tags: functional-analysis

I am just approaching Lorentz spaces, and I have a doubt on an inclusion stated in my professor's notes. He claims that $L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)+L^{3/2}(\mathbb{R}^3)\subset L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)+L^{3/2,\infty}_\epsilon(\mathbb{R}^3)$, where: 
$f\in L^p+L^q$ if $f=f_1+f_2$ with $f_1\in L^p$ $f_2\in L^q$.
$f\in L^\infty+L^{3/2,\infty}_\epsilon$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ we can choose $f=f_1+f_2$ such that $\|f_2\|_{L^{3/2,\infty}}<\epsilon$.
I'm struggling to prove such inclusion, to the point where I'm even doubting if it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throughout, I'm going to work in a measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$. I'm also going to write $p$ instead of $3/2$.

> Claim: If $k\in L^1$ is non-negative, then $$\lim_{t\to\infty}t\mu(\{x\in X:k(x)>t\})=0.$$

We prove this by contradiction. First, suppose that for some $t>0$, $$t\mu(\{x\in X:k(x)>t\})>\epsilon.$$ Define $$f_n=k1_{\{x\in X:t<k(x)<t+n\}}.$$ By monotone convergence theorem, there exists a sufficiently large $n$ such that $$\epsilon/2+\int f_nd\mu=\epsilon/2+\int_{k\in (t,t+n)} kd\mu>\int_{k>t}kd\mu \geqslant t\mu(\{x\in X:k(x)>t\})>\epsilon.$$ Therefore if $t\mu(\{x\in X:k(x)>t\})>\epsilon$, then there exists $s>t$ such that $$\int_{k\in (t,s)}kd\mu>\epsilon/2.$$ Since the sets $(t_n,s_n)$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, are pairwise disjoint, $$\int kd\mu \geqslant \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{k\in (t_n,s_n)}kd\mu=\infty,$$ contradicting the fact that $k\in L^1$.

For a general $p$, $h\in L^p$ iff $|h|^p\in L^1$. By a change of variables $u=t^p$ and using the preceding fact, \begin{align*} \lim_{t\to\infty}t^p \mu(\{x\in X:|h(x)|>t\}) & =\lim_{t\to\infty}t^p \mu(\{x\in X:|h(x)|^p>t^p\}) \\ & =\lim_{u\to\infty}u \mu(\{x\in X:|h(x)|^p>u\}) \\ & =0.\end{align*}

If $f\in L^\infty+L^p$, we can write $f=g+h$ with $g\in L^\infty$ and $h\in L^p$. Then for any $t$, we can write $$f=(g+h1_{\{|h|\leqslant t\}})+h1_{\{|h|>t\}}.$$ For any $\epsilon>0$, we can choose large enough $t$ so that $\|h1_{\{|h|>t\}}\|_{L^{p,\infty}}<\epsilon$, and $$g+h1_{\{|h|\leqslant t\}}\in L^\infty.$$